# Circuit theory paradox - Unexpected results

Tags: electric-circuits, batteries, electrochemistry

I recently studied capacitors and found out that there is something called 'ideal circuit paradox'. Searching Google I found that one can cannot find the potential difference between two points in a circuit where two cells are connected in parallel. So I decided to make a practical circuit.

I connected a  fresh, normal AA Eveready (1.5 V and non-rechargeable) cell with two AA cells in parallel with unsheathed wires and tried to measure the potential difference. The cells were connected in this fashion for about 30 seconds.

The results-

During the exp-
1) The potential difference was continuously decreasing.(approximately about 0.01 Volt per second)

After the exp-
2) The emf of the single cell increased by about 0.2 Volt and decreased by 0.3 Volt for the double cell.

Now my question is-
What exactly is happening inside the cells?

I studied in chemistry that the products formed in the reactions of commercially available primary cells are generally much stable than the reactants. So how can there be a possibility that the reverse reactions took place? 
Please help.

Comment: You can't rely on the assumption that only the primary reactions and their reverse directions are taking place. When you put a large over-voltage on a galvanic cell with aqueous electrolyte, you are likely to produce hydrogen until the electrolyte is dry. The hydrogen will, for a short time, give a secondary cell with a higher circuit voltage. It will also, in a short time, destroy the battery.

Comment: Okay so what's happening?

Comment: What I said: you are most likely generating hydrogen, which gives rise to a second redox-system. It has nothing to do with circuits, though. You are merely using a battery in a different way than it's intended to be used and you are destroying it along the way.

Comment: So, according to you these Eveready cells are generating hydrogen. But what about the preferential discharge theory? (The link http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=http://electrolysis-lucasyhw.wiki.hci.edu.sg/Selective%2BDischarge%2Bof%2BIons&ei=hEpJPJym&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=756&host=www.google.co.in&ts=1466012168&sig=APY536x-l_BqdnSmsLOW6uYyyT21FlPRMw)

Comment: I have no idea what "the preferential discharge theory" is supposed to be. Is that something the electrochemists talk about? To me one would have to analyze the chemical details in the cells you were using, which I have neither the expertise nor the chemistry lab to do. That's really something you need to ask in chemistry.SE.

Comment: Okay. Should I just copy-paste this question

Comment: Ask a moderator to migrate it for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41224/discussion-between-normal-boy-and-curiousone).

Comment: You can contact a moderator using the 'flag' link below the question.  I agree with @CuriousOne that this really seems to be a question for Chemistry SE rather than Physics SE.

Comment: BTW : respect for doing an experiment to test something you had been told.

Comment: I see a distinct lack of close votes and/or flags indicating that anyone considers this question off topic! Remember, that's kind of a prerequisite to migration. (But I'm going to migrate it this time because I think the question is fairly clearly off topic for us.)